# How to block an incoming email in Outlook

Tags: outlook, spam-prevention, email-spam

Not having luck myself, should be simple, but I can't get it to work.

I'm getting spam email from a "Technology Whitepapers".
Their email address is spoofed, with a number:

```
technology-whitepapers.com@mail94.bms2.bmsend.com
technology-whitepapers.com@mail123.bms2.bmsend.com
technology-whitepapers.com@mail42.bms2.bmsend.com
... etc.
```

I tried setting up a rule .. but since the full email is different, that doesn't work.
I tried using a different rule to search for "specific word or phrase in sender's address".  but again, couldn't get it to work.

I tried the Junk mail option of blocking a sender, but the domain changes, so I could only put:
bms2.bmsend.com
which also doesn't work.

So how do you go about blocking an email like this?
I know i'm missing something obvious ...

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue with the same domain

Comment: @TheFluffyRobot Nope .. :(